# Как добавить кнопку по центру в TabBar iOS

Tags: ios

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу добавить кнопку в центр таббара?

Например, как в инстаграм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mouse"];
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
    button.center = self.tabBar.center;
else
{
    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
    button.center = center;
}

[self.view addSubview:button];


-(void)buttonAction
{
    NSLog(@"Нажали на кнопку");
}
```

См. [RaisedCenterTabBar](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar)

Либо можете использовать вот эту библиотеку [EEToolbarCenterButton](https://github.com/el-eleven/EEToolbarCenterButton)

Так же можно посмотреть вот эту бибилотеку [FoldingTabBar.iOS](https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS)   + она кастомизирует tab bar

Comment: Спасибо за множество предоставленных вариантов. Буду сейчас пробовать. Отпишусь по результатам

Comment: Странно, но кнопка создается не в таббаре, а по центру экрана

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin в первом коде изменил концовку, сразу не заметил ошибку. Если не получится, то так же Вы можете попробовать второй код

Comment: Я взял код с RaisedCenterTabBar, там похожий метод.  Сейчас попробую ваш код

Comment: Ни первый, ни второй код ничего не добавляют((

Comment: можете посмотреть мой пример, основанный на первом коде https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LWPa/ZFJnKQN42 . PS: картинка расчитана для iphone 5/6

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin так же не забудьте назначить action на свою кнопку. В ответе подправил код для этого, можете смело использовать его. И убедитесь, что изображение, которое Вы устанавливаете на кнопку, существует в проекте.

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin так же вот мой пример, в котором кнопка остается на месте при повороте устройства https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Kgma/AEYBVNPw9

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin удалось Вам решить проблему?

Comment: Вроде получается, пробую все....
Получается кнопка накладывается поверх таббара, не сдвигая остальные кнопки, так и должно быть?

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin именно. потому что кнопка кладется на View, а не на tabbar. Если вы хотите полностью кастомизировать все детали в tabbar, то легче создать кастомный tabbar с помощью view и button. Либо Вы можете сделать например 5 кнопок в tabbar, одна по-любому будет посередине. Кнопке посередине задать пустое имя и картинку, чтобы она была полностью пустой. Далее используйте мой код и вуаля! У вас будут сдвинуты по две кнопки сбоку.

Comment: хорошая идея, сейчас попробую так сделать и посмотреть что будет

Comment: Да, так нормально! Пожалуй так и оставлю, спасибо за помощь!